# Webcam is not listed in Zoom app

Tags: 18.04, zoom-meeting

My camera is not being listed in the Zoom application.

[image: video tab in Zoom app - no sign of camera]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Ubuntu Software and click **Installed**.

Scroll down to view section Zoom client and click anywhere (don't the button "Remove# :-)

Click the button **Permissions** and change **use your camera** to **ON**.